# How do I find the directory my R session is running in?

Tags: r, filesystems

After writing out a file I want to know where it is, if i use dir i get the files in the current folder but i just want the current folder and dirname is a little obscure

Assuming

```
C\foldername\subfolder1
            \subfolder2
            \subfolder3
                      \file1
                      \file2
```

If r is running in sub folder 3 I will get

```
[1] "file1"                                         
[2] "file2"
```

I want a command that will tell me  C:\foldername\subfolder3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getwd` to get the current working directory.